# How to make a simple popup box in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface, popup

When I click a button, I want a box to popup on the screen and display a simple message.  Nothing fancy really.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("My message here");
```

Make sure the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly is referenced your project.

Comment: Don't forget the semicolon :)

Comment: To add a reference to an assembly in VS, right click on your project and click `Add Reference...`. Then you can search for `System.Windows.Forms`.

Comment: From the `Assemblies` then `Framework` then search for the reference. Not from the COM-tab.

Answer (score 41):

Just type `mbox` then hit tab it will give you a magic shortcut to pump up a message box.

Comment: Note: This only works in Visual Studio.

Comment: When I wrote this comment 12 years ago there was only on family of visual studio ;)

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio 2015 (community edition), `System.Windows.Forms` is not available and hence we can't use `MessageBox.Show("text")`.

Use this Instead:

```
var Msg = new MessageDialog("Some String here", "Title of Message Box");    
await Msg.ShowAsync();
```

Note: Your function must be defined async to use above `await Msg.ShowAsync()`.

Comment: I guess you are checking under UWP or WinRT. `System.Windows.Forms` should still be available, I am fairly sure.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
string text = "My text that I want to display";
MessageBox.Show(text);
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing fancy? Try MessageBox

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s1p9.html

Answer (score 1):

Why not make use of a tooltip?

```
private void ShowToolTip(object sender, string message)
{
  new ToolTip().Show(message, this, Cursor.Position.X - this.Location.X, Cursor.Position.Y - this.Location.Y, 1000);
}
```

The code above will show message for 1000 milliseconds (1 second) where you clicked.

To call it, you can use the following in your button click event:

```
ShowToolTip("Hello World");
```